# Outlook 2007 Addin access value in editBox on custom ribbon

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, vsto, outlook-addin

I am building a Outlook 2007 Addin using with VS2008 using IRibbonExtensibility.

My simple ribbon displays on a MailItem and has a editBox and a button control.  Required functionality is that the user enters a number in the editBox, then clicks the button.  The email message is then saved into a third party system (using the number entered in the editBox as a “primary key” to control location etc)

I am stuck at the point of accessing the value the user has entered into the editBox from the callback function of the button.

I have the follow markup

```
      <editBox
            id="FileNumber"
            maxLength="6"
            label="File No"
            />

      <button
            id="AddEmailTo"
            label="Save to"
            onAction ="AddEmailToButton_Action"
          />
    </group>
  </tab>
```

And the following callback

public void AddEmailToButton_Action (Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonControl p_Control)
        {

```
        //what do I need to add here to access the value in the editBox?
    }
```

Thanks
andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the value in a private variable with the callback onChange

In your class, declare a private variable to store the value of the editbox.
This variable will allow you to get the value of a textbox.

```
private string FileNumberText = "initial value";
```

To initialise a defaut value, use getText callback

```
public string onGetText(IRibbonControl control) 
{   
switch (control.Id)
{
    case "FileNumber":                      
        return FileNumberText ; 
    case "editBox02":
        return "...";
    default:
        return "";
}               
}
```

To record the change of editbox (pass the editbox value to the store variable)

```
        // Recupere le contenu du controle editBox dans la variable Cible
        public void  RecupDonnee(IRibbonControl control, String Text)
        {
            switch (control.Id)
            {
                case "FileNumber":                      
                    FileNumberText = Text.Trim() ;  
                    break;
                case "editBox02":
                    Screen2 = Text.Trim() ; 
                    break;
            }       
        }
```

In your ribbon XAML

```
<editBox 
 id="FileNumber"
 maxLength="6"
 label="File No"                 
 getText="onGetText"
 onChange="RecupDonnee"
 screentip="Tip" 
/>
```